# Почему не выполняется скрипт?

Tags: php, javascript

Я тут балуюсь с suitecrm, и хочу написать скрипт, который модифицирует немного поведение формы. Текстовое содержимое скрипта (ПОЛНОЕ СОДЕРЖИМОЕ файла `/custom/modules/Opportunities/js/customscript.js`):

```
alert('hello!');
```

Далее я скопировал файл `/modules/Opportunities/metadata/editviewdefs.php` в `/custom/modules/Opportunities/metadata/editviewdefs.php`, и изменил кое-что в нем:

```
    $viewdefs['Opportunities']['EditView'] = array(
    'templateMeta' => array('maxColumns' => '2', 
                            'widths' => array(
                                            array('label' => '10', 'field' => '30'), 
                                            array('label' => '10', 'field' => '30')
                                            ),
    'javascript' => '{$PROBABILITY_SCRIPT}',
    'includes' => array(
                        0 => array('file' => '/custom/modules/Opportunities/js/customscript.js'),
                      ),
),
...
```

Возможно, дело в кэше, но чет все равно не работает. Возможно, я что-то упускаю... Новенький =)

P. S. Возможно, я вообще не те файлы правлю, ведь мне нужна форма, которая  появляется при создании сделки...